# MYSQL Split String and Duplicate Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table That looks like this:

```
Col 1.   Col 2.
a        1
b        2
c,d,e    3
```

What I would like to do is run a query that would replace the row with c,d,e with multiple broken out rows so that the result for Select * From table would look like:

```
Col 1.   Col 2.
a        1
b        2
c        3
d        3
e        3
```

Comment: This may be non trivial to do in MySQL, especially if the number of CSV values per row be unknown.  You may wish to export, then handle it in your application programming language.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum number, you can use `union all`:

```
select substring_index(col1, ',', 1) as col1, col2
from t
union all
select substring(substring_index(col1, ',', 2), ',', -1)  as col1, col2
from t
where col1 like '%,%'
union all
select substring(substring_index(col1, ',', 3), ',', -1) as col1, col2
from t
where col1 like '%,%,%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tally table. For example, mine is generated on the fly by recursive CTE

```
with recursive nmbs as (
      select 1 n
      union all
      select n+1
      from nmbs
      where n<100
     ),
testdata as (
      select 'a' c1, 1 c2 union all
      select 'b' c1, 2 c2 union all
      select 'c, ddd  , e ,fgh' c1, 3
)     
select c1, c2, trim(replace(substring(substring_index(c1, ',', n), length(substring_index(c1, ',', n-1))+1), ',', '')) s
from testdata 
join nmbs on n <= 1 + length(c1) - length(replace(c1,',',''))
order by c1,n
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=feeb27966a2c16c8885cf6782f72492a)